# How can I change the Cryptkeeper tray icon?

Tags: icons

I have cryptkeeper on 12.04 working but I don't like the icon. I want to change it to a monochrome icon but I cannot find the icon location anywhere?

I looked in the `/pixmaps` folder and the `/icon` folder and it's not there.

Answer (score 1):

The icon should really be there as the package `cryptkeeper` [contains](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/cryptkeeper/filelist) two icon files.

```
/usr/share/pixmaps/cryptkeeper.png
/usr/share/pixmaps/cryptkeeper.xpm
```

May I suggest you to create your own modified version of the package? Modifying files on your system belonging to packages managed by your package management is not a good idea generally.

Re-building packages and doing your changes is not too hard when it is just concerning some file replacement. Very short how-to: `apt-get source packagename`, `cd packagename...`, do your changes, modify the `debian/changelog` file using `dch`, `debuild -uc -us`, `dpkg -i ...`.